# Excel SUMPRODUCT ignore blank cells or text

Tags: excel

Very new to Excel.
Using the following, =SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(F3:F7,{1,2,3})) to get the sum of the theee lowest cells. It works fine but gives a #Num! error if more than two cells in the range are blank or contain text.
I need those cells blank or with text to be ignored and still return the sum of the three lowest numbers.
Thanks

Comment: If more than two cells are blank or contain text, then you don't have 3 numbers. The problem isn't with `SUMPRODUCT`, it's that there is no 3rd smallest number in that case.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(F3:F7,ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,MIN(3,COUNT(F3:F7))))))
```

Depending on ones version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.

Comment: I've decided to continue using original formula. =SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(E3;E7,{1,2,3}))). It will fit my purpose after all. Now, is there a way to make all zeros display as 'E' but still sum as zero. Thanks again.

Comment: look into custom formatting.  If you need help ask a new question on SuperUser.com.